# how to declare and make objects inside another object's constructor?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++. I am tring to make a couple of objects inside another object but compiler is giving error - **no matching function for call to 'Grass::Grass()'** .

This is the header file of "world" object. In it I declared two "grass" objects :-

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include "Grass.h"

using namespace std;

class World
{
public:
World();

private:
Grass g1;
Grass g2;
};
```

This is the cpp file of the "world" object. In the constructor I tried to make the "grass" objects but failed.

```
#include "World.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

World::World()
{
g1(200, 200);
g2(300, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.  You're looking for what's known as a *constructor initialization list*.  Try (assuming you've got the signature for the `Grass` constructor correct):

```
World::World() : 
    g1(200, 200),
    g2(300, 200)
{
    // Nothing 
}
```

Comment: The constructor initialization list can be used for any member variable that requires construction upon initialization including primitive types.

Comment: @Andy and it should always be used if possible, even if the type has a default constructor, since instead of two calls (ctor + assignment operator) you only call the copy/move ctor.